# XP (in Boot Camp) long lag deleting a file

Tags: windows-explorer, filesystems, boot-camp

I've got a pretty beefy Mac Pro on my desk, and I've used it in Boot Camp mode (with Windows XP) for most of its life.

Every time I delete a file, Explorer hangs for about a minute.  Doesn't matter if it's a small file or a big file (mostly I notice when I'm deleting a wayward shortcut on the desktop) but deletes always take way longer than it makes sense for them to.

What does that indicate?  Boot Camp partition issues?  Anti-virus software making absolutely sure that the file is properly deleted?  TortoiseSVN checking that the deleted files weren't part of some repository?  Windows Indexer being overzealous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Empty the trash.**

When the trash is full and you delete a new file, Windows needs to index the entire can to figure out what to delete.

Alternatively, you can hold down [Shift] when you delete a file to skip the trash can and delete it permanently.

Comment: that, uh, whoa.  that worked.  can't believe I didn't think of that.